# About the passive: "...polluted by chemicals wastes" vs. "polluted because of chemicals wastes"

Tags: grammar

I don't  know if the difference between 2 sentences :

1. *The rivers in this region are polluted because of chemicals wastes from factories.*

...and the second one :

2. *The rivers in this region are polluted by chemicals wastes from factories.*

I wonder which of them is correct answer and do they have any difference?

Comment: "chemicals wastes" is ungrammatical. It should be "chemical waste"; "waste" is usually uncountable, and adjectives are never pluralized.

Comment: You could also say "...are polluted *with* chemical waste from factories".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both sentences are correct and almost have the same meaning. This is what I understand from those sentences.

Sentence 1: The rivers in this region are polluted because of chemical waste from factories.

This sentence tells us that the chemical waste is the **reason** why the rivers are polluted. That's all, nothing more.

Sentences 2: The rivers in this region are polluted by chemical waste from factories.

In sentence 2, we also know the same thing from sentence 1 but there is more thing we can do with the sentence. In this sentence, 'chemical waste from factories' is the **object of the passive sentence** which is **the subject of the active sentence**. So, if you want to change the sentence into active one, you can make it from sentence 2: "Chemical waste from factories pollutes the rivers in this region."

EDIT: I assume that "the river" in the first sentence should be "the rivers" and it was just a typo on your question. Also, I assume it is "chemical waste" instead of "chemicals wastes" because of some comments.

Hope this help.

Comment: Both sentences should say "chemical waste" rather than "chemicals wastes". Or just "chemicals from factories".

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing out the "chemical waste".  I shall edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a very fine point, but I'd say that number 2 is preferable because it is more technically accurate. "Because" indicates a reason or a cause. But the chemical waste did not CAUSE the pollution, it IS the pollution.

Suppose that instead of pollution we were talking about a person. You might say, "On Thursday we were visited by Fred Smith." You wouldn't see, "On Thursday we were visited because of Fred Smith."

Answer (score -1):

The second sentence is correct because the subject "The rivers" matches the verb "are polluted" (both plural). In the first sentence, the subject "The river" does *not* match the verb "are polluted" (one is singular, the other plural).

Comment: I didn't downvote this answer.  I suspect that the downvotes are because you responded (correctly) to a transcription error that the OP has corrected.